# div with horizontal centered text and absolute positioned text in firefox

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I built a div that has horizontal centered text using a table and vertical-align: middle.
I added an absolute positioned text inside that div.

it works on chrome, but not in firefox.

you can see the code and how it's working here.
http://jsfiddle.net/TUwAy/8/

just open it with chrome and see the centered \ absolute positioned texts.

and then open it in firefox and see the absolute positioned text is according to the whole screen rather than the inside the div.

If I remove the table, the absolute positioned text is ok in firefox also, but than I need to find another solution for the horizontal text centering.

any creative ideas in how to solve this?

10x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to be a problem with `display: table` in conjunction with `position: relative`.

How about taking the `absText` out of the "table"?

```
<div class='clickable' id='wrapperID'>
    <div class='tweetclass'>
        <p> horizontal centered text</p>
    </div>
    <div class='absText'>
        <div id='hid'>abs position text</div>
    </div>
</div>

.absText{
    font-size:10px;
    color:#878787;
    font-weight:100;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:7px;
    right:7px;
}

.clickable{
    cursor:pointer;
    position: relative;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TUwAy/15/)

Comment: first of all thanks!, I've been using the position of the 'tweetclass' in javascript by <div class='tweetclass' onclick='showMe(this);'> while in showme(obj) func i use values such as obj.offsetTop,obj.offsetLeft that now have different values, which do not represent its position on the screen. how did this relative affect this?

Comment: `obj.offsetTop` will be the offset to that parent element in the tree that has a `position`, if none found it's the window. Now there is a parent unfortunately.

Comment: the returned offsets are indeed 0 now.so if i want the top and left parameters of this div, any way i can get them?

Comment: You could do `obj.offsetTop + obj.offsetParent.offsetTop` but I advise you to have a look at jQuery for such tasks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an element to be absolutely positioned relative to its parent, the position of its parent must be set to relative.

Comment: It is. There's a position:relative in the parent .tweetclass style.